# Jquery selector, select any DOM element

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm building a cms that can edit design of the page. Let's say effect like SquareSpace. In short a user selects some html element and gets it's CSS properties.

I would like to do this generic, not by adding some class on each element.

Thnx, a lot

Comment: You can use * selector - http://api.jquery.com/all-selector/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

something like

```
$(document).click(function(e){
  $(e.target).css("color", "red");
});
```

[**Example on jsfiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/sVpDG/1/)

Comment: Exactly like that, thank u very much. Idiot me, been searching whole day for that :D

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you need to worry about is event propagation up the DOM tree.  For example, Mark's implementation will change the deepest, original target's style.  What if you want to go higher up, though?  For example:

```
<a href="test.html"><img src="picture.jpg" /></a>
```

Do you want to target the `<a>` tag or the `<img>` tag?

You may want to put some class attributes on the actual targeted elements so you know what you're getting.  You can also use the `live()` handler to do something similar to the method above, but with a little more customization.

```
$('img').live('click', function(e) { /* Do things for images */ });

$('.element').live('click', function(e) { /* Do things for class='element' */ });
```

Be warned that both of these will trigger by default if an element matches both.

See: http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/